# Django Admin dynamic drop down list from list_values

Tags: django, dynamic, drop-down-menu, django-models, django-admin

I have the following models:

```
class Name(models.Model):
    device_type = models.CharField('Device Type', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

class Device(models.Model):
    DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('Router', 'Router'),
        ('Switch', 'Switch'),
        ('Firewall', 'Firewall'),
        ('Load Balancer', 'Load Balancer'),
    )
    device_name = models.CharField('Device Name', max_length=100)
    device_type = models.CharField('Device Type', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Given the above, right now when I create a new object using my Device model, choices for device_type are defined statically using the Field.choices method and this shows up in Django Admin as a drop down list with the four choices shown.

What I really want is to have that list of choices defined dynamically based on the following concept which basically says "from the Name model/table return a list of all values found in the 'device_type' column":

```
Name.objects.all().values_list('device_type')
```

I'm just not sure how to put this into practice.  I'm not sure how to take the list which I already know how to get from my database and incorporate it into the Field.objects method so that those items show up as choices in my drop down menu.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

**UPDATE AFTER FOREIGN KEY FIX:**

Now my models look like this:

```
class Name(models.Model): # device type naming standards
    device_type = models.CharField('Device Type', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    device_alias = models.CharField('Device Alias', max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.device_type

class Device(models.Model):
    location_name = models.ForeignKey('Location')
    device_name = models.CharField('Device Name', max_length=100)
    device_type = models.ForeignKey('Name')
    #device_type = models.CharField('Device Type', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=DEVICE_TYPE_CHOICES)
```

Now you'll see in my Device model I have two ForeignKeys.  I need Location to be a ForeignKey because I want to put Devices categorically under a specific Location.  I need the device type ForeignKey per my previous question.  When I have two ForeignKeys like this, when I go to my Device table in Django Admin, I see no devices (even though they were in the table before I created the device_type ForeignKey.  If I comment out the device_type ForeignKey and uncomment out the last line to go back to what I had before (after updating the schema with 'makemigrations' and 'migrate', now the devices show up again.  Obviously I need the devices to show up in my device table.  Am I allowed to have multiple ForeignKeys?  I'm sure I'm not understanding something critical here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use ForeignKey, you'll get the list of name devices

```
device_type = models.ForeignKey('Name')
   def __unicode__(self): 
      return self.device_type
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: OperationalError at /customers/admin/customers/device/
    no such column: customers_device.device_type_id

Comment: What version of django do you use?

Comment: I had tried that already but wound up with the same error as above because ForeignKey automatically appends _id to the end of the field name and then it doesn't match what is actually in the database.  Also, what if I have to add another field to my Name model?  How would I specify a specific field within ForeignKey('Name') because I tried to figure that out too but couldn't.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7.9 (development only).  I'm a new user.  A few days ago I saw 1.7 was noted on their website as insecure and an upgrade is recommended.  I just haven't done it yet.

Comment: After you changed the data type in model you should tell it to django. Try to type two commands in the projects root `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py makemigrations`, then restart your webserver and try again

Comment: Right, I had done that already as well.  When I look in my drop down menu in the Admin interface, I see "Name Object" listed exactly 25 times.  Well it just so happens that I have 25 "device_type" items in my Name model, but I'm not able to see the actual name in the drop down list.

Comment: In model "Name", after "device_type", write this string `def __unicode__(self):` and this string `return self.device_type`

Comment: And don't forget about indent after the first string

Comment: I had that on my other models but not my Name model.  Oversight on my part.  Thank you very much for the help, I'm in business now.  :)

Comment: OK, now I have a new problem.  And I seem to be unable to post 'code edits' in a comment because whenever I hit 'enter' to go to the next line so I can indent, it posts my comment (this one).

Comment: OK, I added an update to the original post.  See this new section:  **UPDATE AFTER FOREIGN KEY FIX**

Comment: Disregard, I fixed this.  This was a 'data migration' problem because my new ForeignKey didn't have a default value.  I just decided to wipe my database and start over after having migrated to my new schema and repopulated my database with data and now everything works fine.  Wasn't too much trouble as I'm currently using django-import-export to bring data in via spreadsheet.  Thanks again for the help, you got me going!

Comment: You are welcome, check this answer as solved your problem